# Как можно реализовать представление получающее параметр?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, view

Надо сделать представление, которое вернёт должность и отдел сотрудников на заданую дату, например, конец 2007.

Если так:

```sql
create or replace view jobsOnDate as
    select h.employee_id, job_id, department_id
    from hr.job_history h
    where date'2007-12-31' between start_date and end_date;
```

То запрос из `jobsOnDate` конечно работает, но константную дату нужно передать представлению как параметр.

То есть, в идеале создание предстовления и запрос выглядели бы так:

```sql
create or replace view jobsOnDate (effDate date) as 
    select [... where effDate between ...]
/
select * from jobsOnDate (date'2007-12-31')
/
```

Но создать так передставление нельзя. Можно конечно добавить столбцы `start_date, end_date` в сет результата предтавления, но это только пример, реальные данные и запрос намного сложнее, это будет не так просто.

Какие есть пути решения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно решить через [конвеерные функции](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/addci/using-pipelined-and-parallel-table-functions.html#GUID-EFB94CFB-3E44-4236-B490-ADBB480C94D4).

Создаем пользовательские типы данных, они заменят представление:

```sql
create or replace type t_job_history force as object (
  employee_id integer,
  job_id varchar2(10),
  department_id integer)
/
create or replace type t_job_history_tbl as table of t_job_history
/
select * from table(t_job_history_tbl(t_job_history(999, 'UNEMPLOYED', 99)));

EMPLOYEE_ID JOB_ID     DEPARTMENT_ID
----------- ---------- -------------
        999 UNEMPLOYED            99
```

Сама функция:

```sql
create or replace function getJobHistory(inDate date) return t_job_history_tbl pipelined as
begin
  for f_rec in (
    select 
      jh.employee_id, jh.job_id, jh.department_id
    from hr.job_history jh 
    where inDate between jh.start_date and jh.end_date) loop
    pipe row (t_job_history(f_rec.employee_id, f_rec.job_id, f_rec.department_id)); 
  end loop;
  return;
end getJobHistory;
/
```

Вызов очень похож на приведенный в вопросе:

```sql
select *
from table (getJobHistory (date'2007-12-31'))
```

`++` Относительная простота реализации.
`--` Затруднительная оптимизация при использовании функции в сложных запросах.

Comment: `11/15    PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type`. Так работать не будет. У вас нет схемы примеров HR? Если нет, то на LiveSQL она вроде есть, там можно проверить. Кроме того, вы return забыли.

Comment: Я всегда проверяю, то что пишу. На Oracle 11.2.0.3.0 с клиентом 12.1.0.2.0 все работает. Но я переписал на свои типы, чтобы не создавались системные.

Comment: Проверил на схеме HR. Поправил пару ошибок и формат. Вы не против? Если что, то в истории правок есть кннопка откат. Предложения: 1) В пакете теперь только одна ф-я, вынести её из пакета, тогда пример будет выглядеть проще; 2) (--) Собственно самое простое решение, это наоборот (++). А в (--)  упомянуть - затруднительная оптимизация в сложных запросах. Как вы думаете?

Comment: Я не против ни правки, ни предложений. Не сказал бы, что оно прям очень простое (все таки типы создавать), но точно самое правильное. Есть возможность, исправьте, пожалуйста, с мобильного не очень удобно.

Comment: Поправил, проверьте пожалуйста.  _все таки типы создавать_, ну это не аргумент, что-то всё-таки надо будет создавать.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 2):

Один из известных способов, установить параметры в [контексте выполнения](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SYS_CONTEXT.html#GUID-B9934A5D-D97B-4E51-B01B-80C76A5BD086), а представление создать с учётом этих параметров из контекста. Рабочий пример:

```sql
create or replace context myctx using myCtxApi;

create or replace package myCtxApi as
    procedure set (d date, what varchar2 := null);
    function get (what varchar2, forceNull boolean := false) return varchar2; 
end myCtxApi;
/
create or replace package body myCtxApi as
    context constant varchar2 (32) := 'migctx'; 
    procedure set (d date, what varchar2 := null) is
    begin 
        dbms_session.set_context (upper ('myctx'), coalesce (what, 'onDate'), d);
    end set;
    function get (what varchar2, forceNull boolean := false) return varchar2 is 
        ret varchar2 (4000);
    begin
        ret := sys_context (upper ('myCtx'), what);
        if ret is null and not forceNull then 
            raise_application_error (-20000, 'not set in the context '||context||'('||what||')'); 
        end if;
        return ret;
    end get;
end myCtxApi;
/
create or replace view jobsOnDate as
    select h.employee_id, job_id, department_id
    from hr.job_history h
    where myCtxApi.get ('onDate') between start_date and end_date;
```

Перед вызовом запроса необходимо будет установить контехт:

```sql
exec myCtxApi.set (date'2007-12-31')

select * from jobsOnDate;

EMPLOYEE_ID JOB_ID     DEPARTMENT_ID
----------- ---------- -------------
        114 ST_CLERK              50
        122 ST_CLERK              50
        176 SA_MAN                80
```

`++` Контекст будет унаследован в сессиях, участвующих в параллельном выполнении.
`--` Относительная сложность реализации.

Answer (score 2):

Начиная с версии 20c задачу можно решить с [*SQL Macros*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/lnpls/release-changes.html#GUID-0A638FCA-89C2-44E0-A5D5-0D09800D920D). В SQL контексте функция с ключевым словом `SQL_MACRO` будет вызвана на этапе парсинга. В тексте возвращаемого ею запроса параметры будут замещены соответствующими литералами. То есть, функция выполнит роль макроса, а её результат и есть тот запрос, который будет эффективно выполнен.

```sql
create or replace function jobHistView (onDate date) return varchar2 SQL_MACRO is
begin
    return q'[
        select h.employee_id, job_id, department_id
        from hr.job_history h
        where onDate between start_date and end_date]';
end;
/
```

Запрос будет выглядеть так ([на Live SQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/koz7wvnnb1cuwjbhgcwp4aald)):

```sql
select * 
from jobHistView (date'2007-12-31');

EMPLOYEE_ID JOB_ID      DEPARTMENT_ID
----------- ----------- -------------
114         ST_CLERK    50
120         ST_MAN      50
122         ST_CLERK    50
176         SA_MAN      80
```

Answer (score 1):

Mожно решить через переменную пакета. Перед вызовом представления ее устанавливать, а в представлении использовать функцию `pkgViewSet.getJobsOnDate`.

Создаем пакет:

```sql
create or replace package pkgViewSet is
  function getJobsOnDate return date;
  procedure setJobsOnDate(inDate date);
end pkgViewSet;
/
create or replace package body pkgViewSet is
  cDateSet date;

  function getJobsOnDate return date as
  begin
    return(cDateSet);
  end;

  procedure setJobsOnDate(inDate date) as
  begin
    cDateSet := inDate;
  end;
end pkgViewSet;
/
```

Создаем представление:

```sql
create or replace view jobsOnDate as
    select h.employee_id, job_id, department_id
    from hr.job_history h
    where pkgViewSet.getJobsOnDate between start_date and end_date;
```

Использование:

```sql
pkgViewSet.setJobsOnDate(date'2007-12-31');

select * from jobsOnDate
```

`++` Простота реализации.
`--` Инициализация пакета должна происходить в каждой сессии.

---

Никогда так не делал, но всегда очень хотелось.